# How to click a specific link with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to simply click a link whenever someone presses the right arrow key, but nothing is happening.

I've got this link:

```
<a title="party pics! 16" href="/photos/photo/new-party-pics-16/" id="next-in-gallery">
    <img src="http://localhost/static/photologue/photos/cache/thumbnail16.jpg">
</a>
```

and this jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).keydown(function(e){
        if (e.keyCode == 39) { 
           $("a#next-in-gallery").click();
           return false;
        }
    });
</script>
```

Seems to do nothing, though.  Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).keydown(function(e){
        if (e.keyCode == 39) { 
           document.location.href = $("a#next-in-gallery")[0].href;
           return false;
        }
    });
</script>
```

?

Comment: That'll do. Thanks! Can't neglect plain old JS.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("a#next-in-gallery").trigger('click');
```

Comment: maybe you have to remove return false;

Comment: Nope, that doesn't seem to cut it either.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/trigger/ look at the first example you see... that's exactly like it. Maybe there's something else changing the behavior of that anchor? Could you try it on different browsers?

Comment: I haven't tried it on any other browsers, but I'm testing in Chrome, so my confidence is pretty high with that... That's the only JS or jQuery targeting that anchor. I bet it's because the jQuery was above the link and since I didn't do it on ready, it was unable to actually grab the link before it loaded. But then again.. it's a keypress.. so I don't know.